# Estimating variance by regressing squared residuals

Tags: variance, predictive-models, linear, prediction-interval

For a linear regression, one way to estimate the range of a prediction for a new observation is to calculate the prediction interval for the new observation.

What if, instead, the squared residuals were regressed against the initial predictors? Would that be another way of estimating the variance for a new observation? If not, what is that regression actually predicting?

Comment: I’ve definitely seen this done in some econometrics lectures, and I don’t even mean the time series folks doing ARCH/GARCH, though I forget the name they used.

Comment: This is a way of estimating heteroskedasticity as a function of the initial predictors; it can help with both parameter estimation and the estimation of the variance for a prediction.

Comment: Another method is simply to make a regression model for the variance parameter, and then use maximum likelihood. That is what is done with [tag:gamlss]. You can peruse that tag!

Comment: All of this is related to the Huber-White robust sandwich covariance estimator.